# Using Non JADE program for creating an agent on an already running jade platform and then migrating that agent to another platform

Tags: java, agent, agents-jade

Here is my code where manager class(non jade program)  creates an agent successfully in an already running JADE platform but doesn't migrate that created agent to another platform.

Manager.java

```
public class Manager 
{

 public static void main(String args[])

{

 Runtime myRuntime = Runtime.instance();
 myRuntime.setCloseVM(true);

 Profile myProfile = new ProfileImpl();
 myProfile.setParameter(Profile.MAIN_HOST, "192.168.2.9");
 myProfile.setParameter(Profile.MAIN_PORT, "1099");

 ContainerController myContainer =  myRuntime.createAgentContainer(myProfile);
 try
 {
  myContainer.createNewAgent("agent_007", agent_hun_main.class.getName(), null);
 } catch (StaleProxyException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
 try 
 {
  myContainer.getAgent("agent_007").start();
 } catch (StaleProxyException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (ControllerException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }

 }
 }
```

agent.java

```
 public class agent extends Agent
 {
 public void setup()
 {
 System.out.println("hie i am an agent");
 System.out.println(this);
 AID remoteAMS = new AID("ams@localhost:12341/JADE", AID.ISGUID);
 remoteAMS.addAddresses("http://192.168.2.9:7778/acc");
 PlatformID destination = new PlatformID(remoteAMS);
 this.doMove(destination);

 }

 }
```

This is the error that i get while executing my project:-

## Mar 03, 2015 5:25:21 PM jade.core.mobility.AgentMobilityService$CommandSourceSink handleInformMoved

## SEVERE: Destination localhost:1099/JADE does not exist or does not support mobility

Please help in sorting out this problem .
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello stackoverflow !                                                                                      i guess this is an active community or it is the other way round ?

Answer (score 0):

Jade does not support mobility between platforms.
According to the [JADE Programmer’s Guide](http://jade.tilab.com/doc/programmersguide.pdf):

> Using JADE, application developers can build mobile agents, which are
>   able to migrate or copy themselves across multiple network hosts. In
>   this version of JADE, only intra-platform mobility is supported, that
>   is a JADE mobile agent can navigate across different agent containers
>   but it is confined to a single JADE platform

Comment: hey this much i know already so  for THAT there is an IPMS ,please read my question again .